# CSS carousel display using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my page there are totally 9 tabs. Initially i am showing 5 tabs, left and right arrow. When the user clicks the right arrow it has to show the 6th tab and the 1st tab has to hide.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJysg/)

Html

```
<div class="carousel_area">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="carousel">
            <p class="caro_icon"><img src="images/icn_channels.png" alt="Channels"></p>
            <p class="caro_lbl">Channels</p>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="carousel">
            <p class="caro_icon"><img src="images/icn_favourite.png" alt="Favourites"></p>
            <p class="caro_lbl">Favourites</p>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="carousel carousel_focus">
            <p class="caro_icon"><img src="images/icn_feature.png" alt="Featured"></p>
            <p class="caro_lbl">Featured</p>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="carousel">
            <p class="caro_icon"><img src="images/icn_history.png" alt="Recommended"></p>
            <p class="caro_lbl">Recommended</p>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="carousel">
            <p class="caro_icon"><img src="images/icn_playlist.png" alt="Playlist"></p>
            <p class="caro_lbl">Playlist</p>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="carousel">
            <p class="caro_icon"><img src="images/icn_recommend.png" alt="History"></p>
            <p class="caro_lbl">History</p>
        </a>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.carousel_area{
    display:block; 
    width:1152px; 
    height:150px; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0px; 
    left:64px;
}
.carousel{
    display:block;
    width:206px;
    height:100px;
    margin:50px 1px 0px 0px;
    background:#175151 repeat-x;
    float:left;
    text-decoration:none;}
```

The page width is 1280. I have the idea that on click of the right arrow i have to make the fist element left margin to some negative value but i dont know how to do that. I am using jquery. Can anyone help me in this

Comment: I didn't write the jquery. On click of the right arrow i have to change the css position

Comment: I am creating this page for smart tv app. So my idea is not to use the plugins for the carousel. Just i want to move the positions of the tab.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I added one more div called carousel wrapper. In that i fixed the width of the display area and overflow hidden. Then in the carousel_area i removed the overflow hidden and i placed all my tabs. Onclick of the arrow button i changed the margin of the carousel_area.

```
<div class="carousel_wrapper">
<div class="carousel_area">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="carousel">
            <p class="caro_icon"><img src="images/icn_channels.png" alt="Channels"></p>
            <p class="caro_lbl">Channels</p>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="carousel">
            <p class="caro_icon"><img src="images/icn_favourite.png" alt="Favourites"></p>
            <p class="caro_lbl">Favourites</p>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="carousel carousel_focus">
            <p class="caro_icon"><img src="images/icn_feature.png" alt="Featured"></p>
            <p class="caro_lbl">Featured</p>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="carousel">
            <p class="caro_icon"><img src="images/icn_history.png" alt="Recommended"></p>
            <p class="caro_lbl">Recommended</p>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="carousel">
            <p class="caro_icon"><img src="images/icn_playlist.png" alt="Playlist"></p>
            <p class="caro_lbl">Playlist</p>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="carousel">
            <p class="caro_icon"><img src="images/icn_recommend.png" alt="History"></p>
            <p class="caro_lbl">History</p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel_wrapper{
    diplay:block;
    width:1151px;
    height:150px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:64px;
    }

.carousel_area{
    display:block; 
    width:1152px; 
    height:150px;    
    position:absolute; 
    top:0px; 
    left:64px;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('.rght_btn').click(function(){
    left=left-206;
    $('.carousel_area').css({left:left});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all whoever works on Site Pages please avoid width in pixcels unless u r setting min-width, for much better please go with width in Percentage, for example

```
 <style>
 .divimg{
       width:54%;
        }
 </style>
```

if u use like this the image can't get resolution issues

Answer (score -2):

If you need to make a slideshow, it might be easiest to use a jquery plugin. There are literally dozens of jquery plugins that show carousels / slideshows / filmstrips. If you want to do it yourself, there are also hundreds of tutorials online that talk about this. It is now possible to do it using only CSS3, too.

Comment: I want to know how to change the first tab left margin to negative

Comment: How can you classify this as an answer? [answer]

Comment: I was just trying to help someone who doesn't appear to be able to write their own carousel. Even a rudimentary carousel would require at least a few dozen lines of jquery. And what the hell is a "tab"? My solution if I were to do a carousel like this would be to use a plugin. I think it's a valid answer.

Comment: @Priya, use $.animate() to animate your 'margin-left'. You can specify animation speed and a callback. Just read up a little on it, jeez.